# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a new project with selenium but I got this error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: 'de8579b6d5'
System info: host: 'Ginas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:3b:f328:9854:2af1%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.7', java.version: '11.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:501)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:105)
    at contactPolicy.com.gui.DriverSetup.main(DriverSetup.java:11)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is a new error for me and I try to figure out what happened.
this is my class to call the driver, this a maven project.

```
package contactPolicy.com.gui;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class DriverSetup {

    //Constructor
    public static void main (String [] args){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/gicastano/IdeaProjects/contactPolicy/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("www.google.com");
    }

}
```

I tried a lot of solutions that I have been seen but still no success and I feel frustrated, I'll appreciate all help. thanks!

Is a maven project. This is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>contactPolicy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Selenium
         https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
        </dependency>

         https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
        </dependency>


       https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
        </dependency>

        -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: Does driver and browser are having same versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything was normal when I downgraded the version of selenium to 3.141.59

Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}
```

dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```